# How do I import a MySQL database in a Python script?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I've seen some similar questions about this on StackOverflow but haven't found an answer that works; see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408714/execute-sql-file-with-python-mysqldb](http://this%20post) AND [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593876/execute-sql-file-in-python-with-mysqldb?lq=1](http://this%20other%20post)

Here is my code:

```
import pymysql
import sys
import access  # holds credentials
import mysql_connector  # connects to MySQL, is fully functional


class CreateDB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cursor = None
        self.conn = pymysql.connect(host, user, passwd)

    def create_database(self):
        try:
            with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
                for line in open('file.sql'):
                    cursor.execute(line)
            self.conn.commit()

        except Warning as warn:
            f = open(access.Credentials().error_log, 'a')
            f.write('Warning: %s ' % warn + '\nStop.\n')
            sys.exit()

create = CreateDB()
create.create_database()
```

When I run my script I get the following error:

```
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1065, 'Query was empty')
```

My .sql file is successfully loaded when I import directly through MySQL and there is a single query on each line of the file. Does anybody have a solution for this? I have followed the suggestions on other posts but have not had any success.

Comment: Any empty lines in the beginning or ending of the file?

Comment: Consider `if line.strip(): cursor.execute(line)`

Comment: That solved it right away, thank you so much. If you post as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take care of empty lines in the end of the file by:

`if line.strip(): cursor.execute(line)`

Comment: I just deleted all blank lines but this works too, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can execute all the SQL in the file at once, by using the official [MySQL Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) and the `Multi` parameter in its [`cursor.execute` method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html).

Quote from the second link:

> If `multi` is set to `True`, `execute()` is able to execute multiple statements specified in the operation string. It returns an iterator that enables processing the result of each statement.

Example code from the link, slightly modified:

```
import mysql.connector

file = open('script.sql')
sql = file.read()


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='u', password='p', host='h', database='d')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

for result in cursor.execute(sql, multi=True):
  if result.with_rows:
    print("Rows produced by statement '{}':".format(
      result.statement))
    print(result.fetchall())
  else:
    print("Number of rows affected by statement '{}': {}".format(
      result.statement, result.rowcount))

cnx.close()
```