# How to fetch .sql file execution multi results in python mysql connector library

Tags: python, cursor, generator, mysql-connector

I am writing a python AWS Lambda to execute a MySQL file for RDS MySQL database.

So far it looks like it is working. And I was about to test it by printing how many rows are affected or any other response messages.

Here are how my code looks like after multiple changes.
I used this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34275794/how-do-i-import-a-mysql-database-in-a-python-script) link as a reference to update my original code.

```py
import mysql.connector

def handler():
  config = { <RDS MySQL DB username, password and others...> }
  connect = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
  cursor = connect.cursor(dictionary=True)

  file = open('script.sql')
  sql = file.read()


  for result in cursor.execute(sql, multi=True):
    if result.with_rows:
      print("Rows produced by statement '{}':".format(result.statement))
      print(result.fetchall())
    else:
      print("Number of rows affected by statement '{}':{}".format(result.statement, result.rowcount))
```

This code throws `Failed getting warnings; Use multi=True when executing multiple statements`.
At first, I was not sure why it is complaining about it as I already passed `multi=True` to `execute` funtion. However, I am guessing maybe the `result` variable holds the `multi` lines result and I have to loop them to see each query result.

I have tried to iterate them with `for in`, `next`, `__itra__` and others. However, none of them worked.

I also rollback and debugged a bit.

```py
def handler():
  config = { <RDS MySQL DB username, password and others...> }
  connect = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
  cursor = connect.cursor(dictionary=True)

  with open('scripts}', 'r') as sql:
    result = cursor.execute(sql.read(), multi=True)
    print(result)
```

The print function returns `<generator object MySQLCursor._execute_iter at ...>`

So the result is generator object.
I tried to turn this into list and I got this error.
`Failed getting warnings; Use multi=True when executing multiple statements`

Can someone please help me how to resolve this issue?
Thank you very much in advance.