# How can I execute "source FileName.sql" in a python script?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I would like to execute the MySQL query `source FileName.sql` in a Python script on Linux.

I am able to execute other queries like `SELECT * FROM table_name` but this one is giving an error. I am executing this on a Linux server with a MySQL database using Python. The frontend I am using is Putty.

The Python script I have used is:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("hostname","username","pswrd","dbname")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("source FileName.sql")
db.close()
```

How can I execute the query `source FileName.sql` on the location where this file-> `FileName.sql` is located?

Comment: `source FileName.sql` is not a valid SQL statement. So I am not surprised it is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [execute \*.sql file with python MySQLdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408714/execute-sql-file-with-python-mysqldb)

Comment: but when I am executing this SQL statement outside python script, then its working.

Answer (score 4):

`source` is not a SQL command. It's a MySQL CLI command, it only exists in the console application `mysql` (and wherever else implemented). All it does is to read the contents of FileName.sql and issue the SQL commands inside.

To do this in python, you can use something like

**Edit: This assumes you have 1 query per line! If you have multi-line queries, you'll have to find the means to extract each query from the file.**

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("hostname","user","pass","db")
cursor = db.cursor()
for line in open("FileName.sql"):
    cursor.execute(line)
db.close()
```

Comment: its giving below error:  File "test6.py", line 5, in <module>
    cursor.execute(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/*' at line 1")
root@ubuntu:/#

Comment: I've added a comment in the answer, see above. Also, if you have any external commands for the `mysql` CLI tool it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a bash command with Python and import your SQL file.

This exemple is for MySQL

```
import subprocess
command = "mysql -u username --password=p@55W0rD database_name < file.sql".split()
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()  # you can see if errors are returned
```

if your SQL file creates a database, remove *database_name*.

sources:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Separate the scripts in SQL file in python using ";" as delimiter
2. Execute each command iteratively.
3. awesome5team had developed a nice solution in https://github.com/awesome5team/General-Resources-Box/issues/7

Code snippet from the same:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',
                             password='YOUR-PASSWORD-FOR-MYSQL',
                             host='localhost',
                             database='YOUR-DATABASE-NAME')
cursor =cnx.cursor()

def executeScriptsFromFile(filename):
    fd = open(filename, 'r')
    sqlFile = fd.read()
    fd.close()
    sqlCommands = sqlFile.split(';')

    for command in sqlCommands:
        try:
            if command.strip() != '':
                cursor.execute(command)
        except IOError, msg:
            print "Command skipped: ", msg

executeScriptsFromFile('SQL-FILE-LOCATION')
cnx.commit()
```