# Running SQL file from Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mariadb, popen

I have to launch a python sql file.
The file is for mysql.
I tried it like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys


class ImportSql:
    def execImport(self, fileSql):
        try:
            with open(fileSql, 'r') as fileInput:
                proc = Popen(["mysql", "DB_NAME", "-u", "USER", "-pPASSWORD"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
                proc.communicate('source ' + fileInput)[0]
        except BaseException as ex:
            print("ERROR:", ex)
            sys.exit()
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR: must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper

how can I do?

Comment: This one looks like what you want.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4563950/1394353  note what the source is using - the file name, not contents. So dont open the file

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the contents of the file, not the file object.

```
proc.communicate('source ' + fileInput.read())
```

Also, please don't catch exceptions just to print them and exit. That's what Python does already. Leave out that try/except.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I moved the mysql instructions inside a bat.

```
from subprocess import Popen


class ImportSql:
    def execImport(self):
        p = Popen("import.bat")
        p.communicate()
```

it's ok!
thanks!